# Не могу разобраться с создание запроса sql

Tags: php, sql, yii2, sqlite3

Я не силен в sql поэтому не могу понять куда копать и реально ли такой запрос создать?

**Входные данные:**

> site_id, category

**Описание таблиц:**

> таблица1 = список с постами (id, title, content)
>
> таблица2 = архив с данными о опубликованных постах  (id, site_id,
>   post_id, category)
>
> таблица3 = список сайтов

**Задача:**

> выбрать запись из таблица1 если в таблица2 не содержится записи с
>   полями (site_id и category и таблица1->post_id)

т.е. при каждой публикации, в таблица2 создается запись с данными (site_id, post_id, category, time) и нужно чтобы при следущем запросе  (при тех же входных данных) на публикацию, выдача из таблицы1 не повторялась

Пока только так придумал:

```
    $site = ConfigSite::findOne(['id' => $site_id]);

    $archive = Archive::findAll(['id_site' => $site->id, 'category' => $category_title]);
    $posts = Archives::findAll(['category' => $category_title, 'status' => 1]);
    foreach($posts as $post) 
    {
        foreach($archive as $arch) 
        {
            if($post->id === $arch->id_post)
                continue 2;
        }
        $item = $post;
    }
```

Но через пару недель работы такие процедуры буду занимать много времени

Comment: описание структуры таблиц в вопросе не соответствует приведенному коду. У вас в коде category в двух таблицах. А вообще что то вроде `select p.* from posts p left join archive a on a.post_id=p.post_id where p.site=? and a.post_id is null` Ну и еще вам надо придумать, как это переложить на yii2

Answer (score 0):

```
$items = Archive::find()->alias('a')
            ->leftJoin('posts p', 'p.id = a.id_post')
            ->andWhere(['a.id' => $site->id])
            ->andWhere(['p.id' => null])
            ->all();
```